# What's the name of the argumentation position / logical fallacy of saying "well prove it doesn't exist"

Tags: meaning

For e.g someone says they believe in the Flying Spaghetti Monster. When you ask for evidence they reply: "well, prove it doesn't exist!"

Surely it's the prerogative of the believer to provide evidence not the non-believer.

I claimed this was a Strawman argument but I believe that's wrong fallacy example. What is correct name for this argumentation technique?

Comment: The believer is falling back on the 'Argument from ignorance' (appeal to ignorance, argumentum ad ignorantiam) – assuming that a claim is true because it has not been or cannot be proven false, or vice versa. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies)]. I'm not sure there's a term for 'to counter a demand for proof with an argument from ignorance'.

Comment: In science and in most accepted arguments the axiom is 'proof lies in the assertion, not in the negation'

Answer (score 6):

It's called *shifting the burden of proof*.

> **burden of proof**
>   You said that the burden of proof lies not with the person making the claim, but with someone else to disprove.
>   [- yourlogicalfallacyis.com](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/burden-of-proof)

It's related to an [argument from ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance), but is slightly different in emphasis. Instead of claiming that a proposition is true because it hasn't been proven false, it sidesteps the claim altogether and challenges the other person to disprove the proposition.

Answer (score 3):

This is virtually a textbook case of an **argument from ignorance**.

> Argument from ignorance, also known as appeal to ignorance (in which ignorance represents "a lack of contrary evidence"), is a fallacy in informal logic. It asserts that a proposition is true because it has not yet been proven false (or vice versa). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance)

However, the chances are that your interlocutor isn't really committed to [Pastafarianism](https://www.venganza.org/about/), but wants to undermine the alleged pretensions of those who accept more traditional forms of religion by positing an analogy between those religions and belief in the [Flying Spaghetti Monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster#Use_in_religious_disputes).

Comment: This is exactly right.  The Flying Spaghetti Monster argument attempts to argue that one cannot prove that God (or Allah, or *insert name of deity here*) exists any more than one can prove that the Flying Spaghetti Monster exists.  I leave it as an exercise to the reader to decide if this is a valid argument.

Comment: Actually it wasn't the "flying spaghetti monster", it was "the patriachy". But I deliberately used a different example to avoid politically biased responses from people.